# Python: Store content from a text file as a variable in a dataframe

Tags: python, types

So I searched several places for an answer to my question, but it's not showing up.  Maybe it's not possible in Python.

I need to store the content of large text files as a column in a dataframe.  For example:

```
ID Name       Text
1   a   'Full text file 1'
2   b   'Full text file 2'
3   c   'Full text file 3'
4   d   'Full text file 4'
```

I am not storing links or filenames.  I need to store the contents like a really large string (the files contain full documents).  I thought it might be a dictionary or something similar to a blob for text.

I can't seem to find the option to do this.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First create an empty dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'text'])
```

Then you can read the files in a loop, and put them in the dataframe:

```
for file in files_list:
    my_file = open(file, 'r')
    my_text = my_file.read()
    my_file.close()
    df.loc[len(df)] = [file, my_text]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a limit as to how much text I can store?

Comment: I guess it depends on the free memory you have. But don't worry. python would let you know if there's a problem :)